# How to print current Metamask account balance in console.log/HTML

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am trying to print the balance of the current Metamask account in my localhost web app, but in the console log it says

```
   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var num = document.getElementById('num');
var address = document.getElementById("name");

// print current account address and its corresponding balance. The address prints as fine, but not the balance
async function checkBalanceAddress() {
  await window.ethereum.enable();
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  const account = accounts[0];
  console.log(account)
   window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
      // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
      console.log(accounts[0]);
     });
  address.innerHTML = account;
  // uncaught error here
  num.innerHTML = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your import statements as well?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I have already resolved this. Thank you